# LoadLibrary function - compile error

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to build a small program which uses a dll file.
Using VC++ compiler, I get an error saying that:

error C2039: 'LoadLibrary' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C3861: 'LoadLibrary': identifier not found

LoadLibrary is included in winbase.h file and my all files include stdafx.h so, winbase is included already. I could not figure out why it fails to compile...
Here is the code:

```
      if(m_lib) 
     ::FreeLibrary(m_lib);
  if((m_lib=::LoadLibrary(path))!=NULL)
    {
     m_pfnManVersion=reinterpret_cast<ManVersion_t>(::GetProcAddress(m_lib,"ManVersion"));
     m_pfnManCreate =reinterpret_cast<ManCreate_t>(::GetProcAddress(m_lib,"ManCreate"));
    }
```

Thanks in advence.

Comment: interesting that it didn't complain about freelibrary.

Comment: @acraig5075 - "windows.h" is already included in "stdafx.h"

Comment: Errors like those are undiagnosable.  Use LoadLibraryA() instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the windows header file (WinBase.h) you will notice that LoadLibrary is actually a macro definition that redirects you to the unicode or ascii version

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadLibrary  LoadLibraryW
#else
#define LoadLibrary  LoadLibraryA
#endif // !UNICODE
```